# Multi-table inserts in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have four tables

- table_a
- table_b
- table_c
- table_abc

**table_a**,**table_b**,**table_c** contain an auto-incrementing ID as primary key and some arbitrary columns.
**table_abc** have three foreign keys, which are the IDs from **table_a**, **table_b** and **table_c**.

I want to do inserts (atomically, i.e. either all of 1-4 as described below, or none at all) as follows:

1. Make an insert into table_a
2. MAYBE make an insert into table_b
3. MAYBE make an insert into table_c
4. Use the ID(s) generated from inserts 1,2 and 3 respectively to make an insert into table_abc, like `INSERT INTO table_abc (a_id, b_id, c_id) VALUES ([id from insert 1], [id from insert 2 or NULL],[id from insert 3 or NULL] )`

Now for the problem: How do I get the values of the IDs generated by inserts 1,2 and 3 and use them for insert 4? Note that the IDs are not the same for each table, so the **a_id** can be 45 while **b_id** is 10 and **c_id** is 2.

I am using Python and Pandas to make the inserts. I would of course want to store the IDs in python variables after each insert, but I have a feeling that would complicate things since I want atomicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `last_insert_id()`:

```
insert into a ( . . . )
    values ( . . . );

set @a_id = last_insert_id();

insert into b ( . . . )
    values ( . . . );

set @b_id = last_insert_id();

insert into c ( . . . )
    values ( . . . );

set @c_id = last_insert_id();

insert into abc(a_id, b_id, c_id)
     values (@a_id, @b_id, @c_id);
```

Comment: By the way I assume you meant last_insert_id(), not last_insert_id, and set instead of select